# How does typedef with tuples work?

Tags: c, typedef, type-definition

We got this typedef in a homework program. As a programmer noob, I didn't see anything like this before. Does this mean that any DoubleFunction2D is actually a 2-tuple of (double, double)?

Program:

typedefs:

```
typedef double (*DoubleFunction)    (double);      
typedef double (*DoubleFunction2D)  (double, double);    
typedef double (*DoubleFunction3D)  (double, double, double);
```

Example usage
(my WIP solution to a task, not yet complied/tested. Inside):

```
double expf2D(double x, double y)
 {
     double r = sqrt(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2));
     return my_expf(r);
 }

double DiskMonteCarloIntegrator(DoubleFunction2D f, double r1, double r2, int N)
{
    bool is_inside_ring(double x, double y){
        return is_inside_ellipse(x, y, r2/2, r2/2) && !(is_inside_ellipse(x, y, r1/2, r1/2));
    }
    int i=0;
    double x, y, sum = 0;
    while(i < N)
    {   
        x = RandomDouble(-1*r1, r1);
        y = RandomDouble(-1*r1, r1);
        if(is_inside_ring(x, y))
        {
            sum += f(x, y);
            i++;
        }
    }
    double avg = sum / N;
    double integral = avg * (pow(r2, 2) - pow(r1, 2)) * M_PI;
    return integral;
}

//extract
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
    DiskMonteCarloIntegrator(expf2D, 1.0, 2.0, 1000000);
}
```

Comment: typedef-ed pointer to function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no tuples here *(in fact, there are no "tuples" in the C programming language)*.

---

```
typedef double (*DoubleFunction)    (double);
```

*means* `DoubleFunction` is a pointer to a function that takes a `double` and returns a `double`.

---

```
typedef double (*DoubleFunction2D)  (double, double);
```

*means* `DoubleFunction2D` is a pointer to a function that takes two `double` values and returns a `double`.

---

```
typedef double (*DoubleFunction3D)  (double, double, double);
```

*means* `DoubleFunction3D` is a pointer to a function that takes three `double` values and returns a `double`.